# Docker - wordpress deployed on Digital Ocean Droplet - where is the wp-content?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

Testing the Docker eco-system, I deployed my containers with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) on a Digital Ocean droplet (created with docker-machine..)  it's running fine

the *docker-compose.yml* file is quite simple, using standard images

```
web:
    image: wordpress
    links:
     - mysql
    environment:
     - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - wp-content/:/var/www/html/wp-content
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
```

I can easily query the droplet url in my browser.

When I ssh into the droplet, I am searching for the `wp-content` folder in the droplet host, which is mounted as `/usr/www/html/wp-content` but I cannot find it... also the `/var/www/html` directory is empty... but the wordpress container is running

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Could you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

wrong path for volumes wp-content and wrong search in remote host ..
need to run :
docker exec -it  bash to lsit files in container ....